# Excel vba adding spaces to a cell to reach a certain length

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to have the cells in the range A1 to A6 to reach the length of 18.

The current values in it:

```
A233333
A0399
30000
3993833
11111
22222
```

Note that not all the values in the cells have the same length.

I want to fill the remaining length with blank spaces (" "). So I wrote the following code but it does not seem to work:

```
Sub PMAP_BAC_Code()

Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRng As Range
Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A6")

For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
If Len(xCell) <> 18 Then
    xCell.FormulaR1C1 = " "
End If
Next rCell

End Sub
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: you only add one space per cell, and since they only have 5 characters in them, you're effectively turning them into 6-char cells. shouldn't you be adding 13 spaces, not just one?

Comment: Well, for one, you're changing variables. `rCell` then `xCell`

Comment: Do you want the spaces in front?  Note: that even making them all the same length will not necessarily make them line up.  this is because each character has its own width and not all are the same.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that not all the values have the same length. So I need to add to those values, the remaining blank spaces to make it a length of 18

Comment: The spaces would be after the text

Comment: I was thinking of a loop until it reaches a length of 18

Comment: Or just subtract and do `rept`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use `Left$("foo" & String$(17," ") ,17)`?

```
Sub PMAP_BAC_Code()

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rRng As Range
    Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A6")

    For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
    Const lMY_LENGTH As Long = 18
    If Len(rCell) <> lMY_LENGTH Then
        rCell.Value2 = IIf(IsNumeric(rCell.Value2), "'", "") & Left$(rCell.Value2 & String$(lMY_LENGTH, " "), lMY_LENGTH)
    End If
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Folding in feedback from comment about numbers, I have added a single quote for numerics.   Other comments about not lining up the end of the text are still true though.

Comment: String$(n,char) give n instances of the character.  Try this in debug window `?String$(5,"*")`.  Left$ truncates a string to the desired length.

Comment: Brilliant. Even better than `rept`^^

Comment: When I tried it in the loop the numbers get truncated back to numbers.  so the spaces are removed.

Comment: @ScottCraner oh. I would just use formula on sheet? Edit: or does that have same effect? Edit2: tangent - you should check out code review. A whole different level XD Edit3: ignore me.

Comment: @findwindow but OP wants the change in place not in another cell.

Comment: There is a special function for x spaces, called `space()`: `=Left$("foo" & Space$(17) ,17)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
Sub PMAP_BAC_Code()

Dim str As String
Dim wk As Worksheet
Set wk = Sheet1

For i = 1 To 6
    str = wk.Range("A" & i).Value

    Do While Len(str) < 18
    str = str & " "
    Loop

    wk.Range("A" & i) = str
    str = ""

Next i


End Sub
```

If the col A has only numbers like 1 then above code will convert the string "1           " to "1" again so instead I use to concatenate with NBSP which is chr(160) which will take care of it

```
Sub PMAP_BAC_Code()

Dim str As String
Dim wk As Worksheet
Set wk = Sheet1

For i = 1 To 6
    str = wk.Range("A" & i).Value

    Do While Len(str) < 18
        str = str & Chr(160)
    Loop

    wk.Range("A" & i) = CStr(str)
    Debug.Print Len(wk.Range("A" & i))
    Debug.Print Len(str)
    str = ""

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use `Left$("foo" & String$(17," ") ,17)`  You are looping needlessly.

Comment: I don't know maybe I just use the logic he was trying to implement :)

Comment: The problem is the numbers, adding spaces to number gets truncated back to the numbers and it goes into an eternal loop.

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes got it.

Answer (score 2):

Do not forget that [Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/office/gg251755.aspx) can also be used to format Strings:

```
Public Function myFormat(str As String) As String
    myFormat = Format(str, "!" & String(18, "@"))
End Function
```

Edit: My function applied to the current problem:

```
Sub PMAP_BAC_Code()

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim rRng As Range
    Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A6")

    For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
        rCell.NumberFormat = "@"
        rCell.Value = myFormat(rCell.Value)
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Comment: My format function is just an example and give the right result, up the the user to force the format of the cell to text with .NumberFormat = "@" if needed.

Comment: Nice, probably better than mine but we need to know why OP wants to add spaces.  I'm moving off this question now.